# The subset $[a, b)$ of $\Bbb R$ is neither open nor closed.

Tags: general-topology

While reading Topology, J.Munkres (2014), there's a following statement:

> "The subset $[a, b)$ of $\Bbb R$ is neither open nor closed."

To understand this, first I have think first,

1) Is $\Bbb R$ topology? Yes. It contains empty set and itself, while closed under infite unions of its element and finit intersection of its elements.

2) However, I think the set $[a,b)$ is in $\Bbb R$ so it's open. but it says neither one of open or closed.

This apparently looks I am missing something logically, but I am short of it.

Anyone help me to understand and good start with topology?

Comment: Do you know the definition of "open set" in the ordinary topology on the reals?

Comment: Is $\mathbb{R}$ a topology? No. A topology of a set $X$ is a subset of the power set of $X$. If we consider the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ (open intervals forming the basis set) then it is not true that $[a,b)$ being in $\mathbb{R}$ implies that it is open. I think that it would be very beneficial for you to review the definition of a topology.

Comment: @user328442 I know that topology is a set which is generated by another original set. But topology is not a function since there can exist mulitple different toplogies on a given original set. And moreover, we call a element that is in toplogy  $\tau $ "open in a $\tau$". Now on the OP, we have to think which "topology" does that "open nor closed" being referred from. Isn't that $\Bbb R$ which is considered as toplogy in this case?

Comment: @delinco part of my point is that there is a difference between the topology and the set of interest (in this case $\mathbb{R}$). The topology is a set of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ as opposed to a set of real numbers in this case.

Comment: @user328442 I see. I looked back to my textbook and I found I just missed "standard topology on R" in mischief manner

Answer (score 2):

Assume that intervals of the form $[a,b)$ are open in $\mathbb{R}$ with $b\in\mathbb{R}$. Then since $\mathbb{R}$ is open (it is in fact both open and closed) then $\mathbb{R}\setminus[a,b)=(-\infty,a)\cup[b,+\infty)$ must be closed. But then $(-\infty,a)\cup[b,+\infty)$ can be expressed as the union of three sets $(-\infty,a)\cup[b,c)\cup(d,+\infty)$ with $b<d<c$ which is again open since all three sets are open. Therefore a contradiction. Next assume that intervals $[a,b)$ are closed with $b\in\mathbb{R}$. By definition any sequence $(x_n)\subseteq [a,b)$ if it converges its limit point is still in the interval $[a,b)$. Take $x_n:=b-1/n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. You can convince yourself that for each $n$ it holds $x_n\in[a,b)$ but $\lim_nx_n=b\neq[a,b)$. Hence $[a,b)$ is not closed either.

Answer (score 0):

"The subset $[a,b)$ of $\mathbb R$ is neither open nor closed." is a true statement.

Note that it is not open because there is no open interval around $x=a$ which is entirely included in  $[a,b).$

It is not closed because its complement  $$(-\infty ,a)\cup [b, \infty )$$ is not open.

Answer (score 0):

It is not closed since $b_n=b-{{b-a}\over n}\in [a,b), n>0$ $lim_nb_n=b$ is not an element of $[a,b)$. It is not open since the intersection of every open interval whose center is $a$ with the complementary space of $[a,b)$ is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

When author doesn't mention about topology on $\mathbb{R}$ , that means you have to consider usual or standard topology on it .

It means under usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ , subset $[a,b)$ is niether open nor closed.

Since :

1. every open set containing $a$ is not contained in $[a,b)$ so given subset is not open in $\mathbb{R}$
2. point $b$ is limit point/accumulation point but doesn't belong to $[a,b)$ so given subset is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: What is usual topology on R?

Comment: A collection of subsets of R which can be can be expressed as a union of open intervals forms a topology on R , and is called usual topology on R.

Comment: open intervals are open sets in this topology